# Sanitize user given column name in SQL Server via C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

In C# I have the following function:

```
public bool Set(int id, string columnName, object value)
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This function sets the given column name to the given value for the given id.
    /// Returns true if the operation was successful, false otherwise.
    /// </summary>

    string query = "UPDATE " + TableName + " SET " + columnName + " = @value WHERE id = @id";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);

    ....
```

I cannot set `columnName` as an parameter, that does not work. However the column name should be a user input. How can I make this sanitize?

I tried making `columnName` an variable like this `@columnName` and setting it later, however, this does not work because I think SQL Server interprets this as a string later, not a column object.

Comment: Honestly, these "one size fits all" queries are normally more hassle than they are worth; why do you want/need one, rather than having appropriate objects/statements for the appropriate table(s)?

Comment: It also doesn't help that with this solution, you have no way of providing the correct data type for `@value`; you'll have to always provide an `nvarchar` of a long length, and hope that implicit conversion doesn't knacker anything.

Comment: You'll need a little helper function that performs the moral equivalent of `$"[{id.Replace("]", "]]")}]"`. This gets more complicated if it's possible the object name is already escaped, or contains a schema (`[dbo].[Table]`), this requires a little parser. If at all possible, avoid such setups in favor of things like Dapper to eliminate boilerplate; dynamic SQL where you have to interpolate identifiers should be left to cases where it's the only option (which is rare outside of ETL tools).

Comment: I don't see how you could sanitize this without round-tripping additional queries, e.g.: query `sys.tables` for the official name and object_id of a table, then query `sys.columns` for the official name of the column in the table, then use those in your query instead of the tainted user input.

Comment: Note also that it's *very* inefficient to use this function to set multiple columns on the same row by calling it column-for-column, so if you're thinking of doing that, don't.

Comment: Now that we are through the "don't do it" replies and when you are still not convinced of not doing it at least whitelist the allowed Tablenames/Columnames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I felt like writing something for this anyway, because I don't write a lot of C#. I do, however, want to repeat that everything in the comments is *still* true; just *don't* do this.

That being said, what you can do if pass parameters for the object names, the id and the value, and then create a dynamic SQL statement, checking against the system objects. This results in some (awful abomination) like this:

```cs
String sql = @"DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
               SELECT @SQL = N'UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + N' SET ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + N' = @Value WHERE id = @Id;'
               FROM sys.schemas s
                    JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
                    JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
               WHERE s.name = @Schema
                 AND t.name = @Table
                 AND c.name = @Column;
               IF @SQL IS NOT NULL
                   EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Id int, @Value nvarchar(4000)', @Id, @Value;
               ELSE
                   THROW 56725, N'Object not found for update.',16;";
try
{   
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        
        command.Parameters.Add("@Schema",SqlDbType.NVarChar,128).Value = schemaName;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Table",SqlDbType.NVarChar,128).Value = tableName;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Column",SqlDbType.NVarChar,128).Value = columnName;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Id",SqlDbType.Int).Value = idValue;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Value",SqlDbType.NVarChar,128).Value = updateValue;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("Update Complete.");

    }   
}
catch (SqlException e)
{
    //Raise appropriate exception, I just dump errors to the console
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Update Failed.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to "sanitize" your input is to try to find the table name and column names in the system tables and do it using a parametrized query.

```
SELECT *
FROM SYS.SYSOBJECTS SO
JOIN SYS.SYSCOLUMNS SC ON SC.id = SO.id
WHERE SO.XTYPE = N'U'
AND SO.NAME = N'TABLE NAME'
AND SC.NAME = N'COLUMN NAME'
```

**disclaimer**: I'm not a big fan of doing things the way you are doing nor doing stuff that needs sanitized user inputs. You need to question those things first.

Comment: Why [`sysobjects`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysobjects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and `syscolumns`? They are designed for **SQL Server 2000** databases.

Comment: @lamu OP doesn't state the version in his/her question and I'm sure this will work in any SQL Server from 7 to 2017 and even if using Oracle the core of the answer holds. The core being don't do it =D

Comment: SQL Server 2000 went *completely* out of support well over a *decade* ago, @Jean . If the OP is using SQL Server 2000, there is a *much bigger* problem at hand.

Comment: @lamu I see your point and maybe you can write an answer using the latest novelties but you and I know sysobjects will be around one more decade or while SQL SERVER exists.

Comment: Note that even if you use this, you *must still escape the interpolated identifier in the final query*, or else have this query give back the `QUOTENAME`d versions of the name, otherwise queries can still break on table names that are interesting (spaces, for example) or malicious (if there's another part of the system that allows users to create tables with arbitrary names).